# How to get number of line in UILabel when it's create using Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I create a one `UILabel` using Auto Layout in `UITableViewCell` that automatically sets number of line when text is assigned.

But how can I find what number of line is there in the label

```
lblDesc.text = [self strClearTextMessage:[distSmartcategoryDetil objectForKey:@"description"]]; 

CGRect textRect = [lblDesc.text boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(292*screenScal, 9999) options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: lblDesc.font} context: nil]; 

CGSize size = textRect.size; 

int numberOfLines = size.height / 12.0 * screenScal;
NSLog(@"numberOfLines %d",numberOfLines);
```

I try many line of code like above but can't able to get perfect number of line

Comment: your label width is fixed ? i.e. 292

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label sizeToFit];
float numLines = label.frame.size.height / label.font.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"numLines %f", numLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you

I get perfect line by using ceil function.

```
int numberOfLines = ceil(textRect.size.height / lblDesc.font.lineHeight);
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if your text contains emoji.

Comment: @OlDor then how can i achieve this.can you help to get number of line of UILable that design with constraint (autolayout).